# Blender lags when clicking open image button

Tags: image, file-browser

I have been working with blender for over 6 months and experienced no problems. However, now, when I click the `Open Image` button, (which is there for background images, environment texture, image textures, etc.), it suddenly freezes for a long time and then the image window is opened.

[image: Before clicking...]

[image: After clicking....]

[image: Window appears after sometime...]

Why am I experiencing such a strange issue?

By the way, I can't find something called `bug` tag, So I have placed some wrong tags as SO insists on adding tags.

Comment: There is no bug tag on the blender stack exchange because blender stack exchange is not the right place to file bugs. But if your not certain its a bug then ask away.

Comment: This is often caused by blender file manager trying to access unreachable locations, like remote hard-drives or networked resources. Try disconnecting all possible sources of problems of this kind temporarily and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is automatically solved when I opened it. But I still curious why it occurred..

Comment: Wait, this problem is again repeating.... Why is it fluctuating like this?

Comment: Can anyone give a permanent solution for this?

Comment: Do you have any faulty drives? I sues to have a bad bluray drive that causes these types of slowdowns, disabling it solved the problem

Comment: Fixed IT! Thanks for spotting out the mistake. I just removed a compact disk from cpu and it fixed the issue.